# User downvoted my question without reading it carefully, what to do now?

Tags: support, downvotes

I asked a question properly and put all the relative code and described the problem I am facing clearly, but user down voted my question without reading it properly. this is the link to my question [How to load interstitial ads in adview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491699/how-to-load-interstitial-ads-in-adview?noredirect=1#comment54768305_33491699) .

below are the comments to support this.

> downvotes? why? any specific reasons or is it your ads are also not
>   loading – Karan Mer 37 mins ago
>
> I think you have not add interstitial Id please Read careful Link that you given.. – Destro 32 mins ago
>
> I have added it check the posted code properly, R.string.banner_ad_unit_id – Karan Mer 32 mins ago

Comment: You have *one* downvote (at the time of writing).  **Relax.**

Comment: @BoltClock I am unable to understand what I didnt read, Its not for one or two downvotes, but this is happening once in a while.

Comment: First of all, there is no clear indication in the comment that the user is the downvoter. Don't assume. He may just have provided that comment to you unrelated to your earlier comment. And other than for making sure your question is actually as good as it can be there is nothing you can do. Move on.

Comment: You don't seem to be showing any work with debugging the problem. Basically you just posted your code, and stated it's not working and there are no errors. Surely you can do some debugging to find somewhere in your code that you are not getting an expected value.

Comment: Yay for the Meta effect not kicking in on the linked question. (Well, except for one downvote.)

Comment: Yo had a problem.  You posted on SO. Your problem got fixed.  Why are you moaning, again?

Comment: Dangit, looks like [Tim lost  his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/163903) AGAIN!

Comment: @tnw Assuming that every single downvote you get must be for a senseless reason is a highly unproductive approach to using the site.

Comment: @Servy That's not the point of that post.

Comment: @tnw It's not the point of that post, but when you say, "Looks like Tim lost his keys again" you're asserting that the "it was some random unrelated uncontrollable force that cause it" is what applies here.  While that *does* happen, and sometimes you *do* need to just ignore a downvote, that should be a last resort, after you've spent some serious time trying to figure out what the real problem(s) with the post are.

Answer (score 5):

> what to do now?

Move on.

Down votes come for a variety of reasons from a variety of users. Unfortunately, for you, in this case some users seem to have either misunderstood your question or thought it was not a good question. They voted accordingly.

According to [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629397/karan-mer?tab=reputation&sort=graph), this seems to be a rare thing for you. Congratulations. In your 48 questions and 182 answers, you are doing something right.

The best advice I can offer is to accept the downvotes, because the only other thing you'd be able to do is [disassociate your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account) from the question. You did receive three answers that look, *at least*, helpful. Not being an android developer, I can't evaluate the answers on their technical merits.

Everyone asks a bad question. Even if you don't think it's bad, it still happens. Accept the hit, hope one of the answers helps, and come back tomorrow with a good question or answer to make up for the few points you lost today.